# php , replace code with php 5.3 compatible code

Tags: php, compatibility

i need to rewrite this function to be compatible with php 5.3

```
function fns_data($address)
{
if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$", $address))
{return true;}
return false;
}
```

anyone can help?

thanks

Comment: http://devthought.com/2009/06/09/fix-ereg-is-deprecated-errors-in-php-53/

Comment: While you're at it, you could swap out the whole regex for a more valid one. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Just a general coding tip: You can remove the `{ }` brackets from that return-statement. If there are no such brackets after an if/for/while then the first statement/line (ending with ";") gets called. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ereg expressions to preg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, changing ereg to preg is (usually) as simple as renaming it to "preg_match" and adding a `/` to the start and end of the pattern. Since your pattern is (relatively) simple:

```
function fns_data($address) {
   if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$/', $address)) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out filter_var(), new to PHP at version 5.2.0:

```
function fns_data($address)  {  
    return filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use ereg, but preg_replace, and use a correct email regex, like this one :

```
function fns_data($address) {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $address))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

even better, you can now use [filters](http://php.net/filter) :

```
function fns_data($address) {
    return filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```